# Android using intents to control media player?

Tags: java, android

I want to send a broadcast (or is it an intent?) from my app that will go to the next track of a music player if something is playing, or play/pause, etc. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

However as far as I can tell from my testing this code snippet doesn't quite do anything. Btw I put this code into a function and call it from a background service, in case that's relevant.

So how can I get this functionality working? If it's not possible for some reason I'm open to suggestions for work-arounds and/or alternate solutions.

Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you accepted permissions in the target app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT` improperly.  See [Intent#EXTRA_KEY_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_KEY_EVENT).  You need to instantiate a new `KeyEvent` object with the `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` keycode.  Just passing the keycode in the intent is passing it as an Integer, not as a `KeyEvent`.

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/tasker/browse_thread/thread/f0d1519e72352a90) shows an example of creating the `KeyEvent` object.

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT));
sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
```